# What are the event names for when a spot instance is created?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-event-bridge

I would like to receive an email notification whenever a spot instance is created or a spot instance request is made.

Is an `eventName` of `RequestSpotInstances` correct or are there other appropriate event names?

```
`resource "aws_sns_topic" "spot_instance_notification" {
  name = "SpotInstanceNotificationTopic"
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "spot_instance_creation_rule" {
  name = "SpotInstanceCreationRule"

  event_pattern = <<EOF
  {
    "source": ["aws.ec2"],
    "detail-type": ["AWS API Call via CloudTrail"],
    "detail": {
      "eventSource": [
      "ec2.amazonaws.com",
      "rds.amazonaws.com",
      "s3.amazonaws.com"
    ],
      "eventName": ["RequestSpotInstances"]
    }
  }
  EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_target" "sns_target" {
  rule        = aws_cloudwatch_event_rule.spot_instance_creation_rule.name
  target_id   = "spot-instance-sns-target"
  arn         = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "email_subscription" {
  topic_arn = aws_sns_topic.spot_instance_notification.arn
  protocol  = "email"
  endpoint  = "myemail@gmail.com" 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You technically can have multiple event names depending on [how you launch spot instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-best-practices.html#which-spot-request-method-to-use):

- `CreateAutoScalingGroup`
- `CreateFleet`
- `RunInstances`
- `RequestSpotFleet`
- `RequestSpotInstances`

If you're using the legacy `RequestSpotInstances` API, then yes - your event type is correct though I would advise to start using a different API.